# vscode extension development: svelte content not loading in webview after building the vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I am building a vscode extension by using svelte for webview. I am following https://youtu.be/a5DX5pQ9p5M. But the deployment of extension is not mentioned in the tutorial .

So i am following https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension.

So after packaging the extension with vsce package and installing the extension the extension doesn't load svelte content but when running in developer mode everything works fine.

I tried creating the package extension multiple Times but still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if all necessarily files are included via:

```bash
vsce ls
```

(You can also open packaged extensions, they are just ZIP-archives with a different extension.)

If they are not (e.g. `src` is excluded by default), you probably can create a [`.vscodeignore`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#using-.vscodeignore) file and manually specify what to exclude.

Running extension problems can be inspected via `Help > Toggle Developer Tools`, usually you will find some errors in the console.

I do not know if debugging forces the extension to load, but if so, make sure you have set the correct [`activationEvents`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events).

Comment: thank you, this worked , removing /out folder from vsignore was the solution where the compiled javascript was added.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was about to remove svelte completely since I couldn't get it to work once built/published. I followed a tutorial which was putting svelte related files in out/compiled and didn't check the .vscodeignore!